# Does IOSTATS show output since boot or since last execution?

Tags: linux, iostat

I see conflicting information online about use of IOSTAT.  In particular I would like to be able to show an average since boot.  Based on information I have read if I have never issued the command IOSTAT it will show the average since boot.  But if at some point I have issued an IOSTAT command the next execution will not be since boot, but rather since last execution.

How do I execute IOSTAT since boot assuming I have already run it once before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`iostat`](https://manpages.debian.orgbuster/sysstat/iostat.1#DESCRIPTION) displays stats since boot, *once* (per command run, not per boot). Then depending on parameters (eg: running `iostat 2`, for every two seconds), it will display stats since previous display in the same command run:

> The **first report** generated by the iostat command provides statistics
>   concerning the time **since the system was booted**, unless the -y option
>   is used (in this case, this first report is omitted). **Each subsequent
>   report** covers the time **since the previous report**. All statistics are
>   reported each time the iostat command is run. The report consists of a
>   CPU header row followed by a row of CPU statistics. On multiprocessor
>   systems, CPU statistics are calculated system-wide as averages among
>   all processors. A device header row is displayed followed by a line of
>   statistics for each device that is configured.

Really `iostat` is just doing a few substractions. The bookkeeping role is done by the kernel. `iostat` just accesses various `/proc` (or perhaps other similar entries). Among them (found simply by using [`strace`](https://manpages.debian.org/strace/strace.1) on `iostat 2`):

```
/proc/diskstats
/proc/uptime
/proc/stat
```

First read is since boot. To know since its last display, the `iostat` memorizes  (while it's running, in memory) the previous values, and substracts them to the newly read: that's what happened during the time period.

To confirm OP's questions: every run of `iostat` command is independant of other runs of the `iostat` command. It won't affect an other concurrently running `iostat` command or future runs of the `iostat` command.

Comment: How do I execute IOSTAT since boot assuming I have already run it once before?

Comment: Maybe I don't understand 'the first report'.  If I log in and issue IOSTAT - is this a first report?  If I then log out and log back in (without reboot) and issue IOSTAT is this also a first report?

Comment: if you type: iostat, you get a first report. If you type again iostat, you get **again** a first report: it's only within the same command that it matters. two different iostat commands bear no relation between them nor will they alter future commands.

Comment: Perfect, now I get it..  Thanks!

Comment: So, please confirm - regardless of historical usage on this system, if I issue `iostat` with no parameters I will get averages since boot.  But if I instead issue `iostat 5` (include an interval parameter) I will get multiple reports - the first of which is since boot, but all subsequent is since the previous.  Is this true?